# Someone knows how can i replace the content of "umdModuleIds" property in Angular 13 ng-package.json file please?

Tags: angular

If use this property in my angular library I have this error :

Building Angular Package
Configuration doesn't match the required schema.
Data path "/lib" must NOT have additional properties (umdModuleIds).

Thanks in advance

I try to upgrade my library based in angular 12 to angular 13 but "umdModuleIds" property is not allowed now in ng-package.json file with angular 13 or greater version of angular.